# writing a count program to find the number of repeatitions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a code to count the number of times a time duration in column B is repeated.After writing a code according to my logic I am still getting error or no output. Here's the app script code  I have written. Help me out.

```
function count() {
    var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = data.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var sh = sheet.getRange('B1:B' + lastRow);
    var cell = sh.getValues();
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; j++) {
        var column2 = cell[i][1];
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            var column4 = cell[j][1];
            if (column4 == column2) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        sheet.getRange('F' + (i + 1).toString()).setValue(count);
    }
}
```

[image: input data]

This is the intended output instead of column F i put the sample output in column C 
[image: sample output]

Comment: Can you provide any example data with your question?

Comment: I have attached a image above check it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: I want to know how many times a value in column B has repeated and display it in column F

Comment: Can you more clearly specify what you intend the output to be? It's difficult to figure out what exactly you're trying to do. The most effective way of communicating this would be to provide a small snippet of input and expected output. This should be presented as text and not as images. Please see [the instructions on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @KumaraGuru you are not providing a sample output, we need to see exactly what you want the output to look like, even if you have to hardcode type it.

Comment: I am getting output as zero in column F1 only, remaining all cells in F has no values

Comment: *I want to know how many times a value in column B has repeated and display it in column F* If this is addressed to me(use @ to notify me or others like @TheMaster), Did you read the answer in the question I linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue(s):

- Outer loop's increment variable doesn't change.

  ```
    for (var i = 0; i < lastRow;/*i never changes =>*/ j++)
  ```
- Date/Time are retrieved as JavaScript objects and cannot be compared with `==`:

  ```
    if (column4 == column2) {//Date objects cannot be compared
  ```
- `cell` doesn't have a value at array index `[1]`

#### Solution:

- Increment all variables in the for -loop
- Compare value of date objects instead
- Array indexes start at `[0]`

#### Snippet:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; ++i) {
var column2 = cell[i][0];
/*....*/
  var column4 = cell[j][0];
  if (column4 - column2 === 0) {//@see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994
```

Comment: I am still getting the whole column C values zero not the count

Comment: Column A do not have any connection with column B and for information column A in almost all cases is unique and repeatition is very few whereas for column B it repeats a lot

Comment: @Kumara  You're only getting one column (col B). Arrays start at `[0]`. Column A is irrelevant.

Comment: Now its working I moved the count variable inside the first loop